# Assigning list of child objects to list of type parent class

Tags: java, inheritance, covariance

I was trying to assign a list of child objects to a list where the type is of the parent class. See code below.

```
class Vehicle {

    public int getCylinders() {
        return 0;
    }

}

class V4 extends Vehicle {

    public int getCylinders() {
        return 4;
    }

}


class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
        Vehicle dodgeV4 = new V4();
        vehicle = dodgeV4;                // no compiler error, parent class type can be assigned a child object

        List<V4> dodgeV4s = new ArrayList<V4>();
        List<Vehicle> vechicles = dodgeV4s;       // A: compiler error
        List<Vehicle> vechicles = dodgeV4s.stream().map(v4 -> v4).collect(Collectors.toList()); // B: no compiler error

    }
}
```

Regarding A, I searched a bit and found it could be due to "covariance and contravariance". What I am curious about is B, why does that work, is there an implicit cast happening there? And is that a reasonable approach if I want to carry out this assignment?

Thanks!

Comment: `vechicles = dodgeV4s` is not allowed; otherwise you could add any `Vehicle` (not only `V4`) to `vehicles`, but that is the same list as `dodgeV4s` - so later list would hold vehicles that are not only `V4`

Comment: These 2 approaches have a difference at one point: one creates the new list to store new elements, and one doesn't.

Comment: The duplicate discusses `Optional#map`, but that works the same as `Stream#map`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a concrete example to see why you can't do that :

```java
List<V4> v4List = new ArrayList<>();
List<Vehicle> vehicleList = v4List;

vehicleList.add(new V3());
```

V3 being another subclass of Vehicle. Let's see what we did : we created a list of V4, therefore only V4s and subclasses of V4 can be added to the list. Then we create a variable linked to this list, but declared as a List. So we can add ANY vehicle in it right ? Well, you can see that there is a problem : we are adding a vehicle that is not a subclass of V4 in the list. Therefore you can't do that. Your example with a map method works because the list of vehicle is... a list of vehicles that is NOT the same list as the previous one, it's a new one.